# Список модулей linux: /proc/modules

Tags: linux

Есть задание с помощью С вывести информацию о загруженных в данный момент модулях. Я делаю так: читаю из файла `/proc/modules` информацию. Но возникла проблема с пониманием того, что в этом файле. Вот фрагмент:

```
v4l2_common 15681 1 videobuf2_core, Live 0x0000000000000000
videodev 153793 3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,v4l2_common, Live 0x0000000000000000
media 21903 2 uvcvideo,videodev, Live 0x0000000000000000
rfcomm 69509 8 - Live 0x0000000000000000
bnep 19624 2 - Live 0x0000000000000000
bluetooth 446409 22 btusb,rfcomm,bnep, Live 0x0000000000000000
6lowpan_iphc 18702 1 bluetooth, Live 0x0000000000000000
binfmt_misc 17468 1 - Live 0x0000000000000000
acer_wmi 32522 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
```

Я полагаю что первое - это имя (`v4l2_common`), второе - размер (15681). А вот дальше не понятно.

Кто-то может объяснить?

Comment: Количество ссылок, зависимые модули. дальше хз что там за Live м адреса, загляните в исходники ядра посмотрите

Comment: я не совсем понимаю как это сделать, где искать

Comment: Ну можно остановиться на известном. мне лично это Live и адреса не кажутся важными сведениями. И `lsmod` это не кажется важным, он это не отображает

Comment: смотрите linux/kernel/module.c предпоследнее поле может быть Live/Loading/Unloading последним идут некие флаги модуля. флаги могут быть различны в разных версиях ядер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

запрос в поисковик строки `/proc/modules`, [первый же результат](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-modules.html).

мой вольный перевод (номер пункта — это номер столбца):

1. имя модуля
2. размер (в байтах) занимаемой модулем памяти
3. количество загруженных экземпляров модуля. ноль — модуль выгружен
4. список модулей, зависящих от данного (хотя по ссылке написано, насколько я понимаю, обратное)
5. текущее состояние модуля: `Live` — загружен, `Loading` — загружается и `Unloading` — выгружается
6. текущее смещение в памяти программы *linux*, по которому загружен модуль

Comment: Пункт 3, на самом деле - количество зависимых модулей. Т.е. сколько модулей придётся выгрузить, если выгрузить этот.

Comment: @Sergey, да, я это знаю, и так и написал. но в приведённой ссылке, насколько я смог понять неродной мне английский, написано, кажется, противоположное — «список модулей, **от которых зависит** данный модуль».

Comment: В этой ссылке написано: "The third column lists how many instances of the module are currently loaded." А это уж - полная чушь. Так что я бы с осторожностью отнёсся к этому источнику. Я смотрел исходы ядра, но сразу найти это место не удалось. Так что не буду говорить про 100% уверенность..